# How can i create watchdog timer using c++ and boost

Tags: c++, boost

What is the best and shortest way to create a WatchDogTimer class, which can wait some time and then died?

So when I'm doing something like

```
WatchDogTimer wdt (10);
```

`wdt` will be available only in next 10 seconds.

How can I do this?

ps: yeah, I saw [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015494/can-i-create-a-software-watchdog-timer-thread-in-c-using-boost-signals2-and-thr) thread, but it did not actually help.

Comment: You can't. When you allocate something that way, you're allocating it on the stack. The only thing that will remove it from the stack is exiting the scope (i.e. returning from the method) containing that variable. In other words, nothing you can control in terms of time. You COULD do it using threads or signals, but the object itself would need to be allocated on the heap (i.e. use the `new` operator). Please give us an example of WHY you want to do this, it may help us give more intelligent answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object on the heap with `new` and hand it to a `shared_ptr`.  Then hold that shared pointer only from a thread that sleeps for 10 seconds before exiting.  Make sure the thread is the only instance of `shared_ptr` and all other references are `weak_ptr`s.  After the 10 seconds `weak_ptr::get()` will return null.