# how to create Timer task in c++.?

Tags: c++, timer, task

can any one tell me how to create a time task which will execute the task periodically if the Particular message is not received within time. the Message receiving is another separate thread.

eg.
if message1 is not received within 5 min in thread 1 then the thread 2 executed a task and again starts to monitor for next 5 min
if message received the thread 2 should not execute the task but keep on monitor for next 5 min ..

this process is ever running Process..

Comment: search for: timers C++ either on SO or google, there are lot's of ways of doing this..

Comment: Your question is probably specific to Windows, and should have been tagged as such.

Comment: If you can use boost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015494/can-i-create-a-software-watchdog-timer-thread-in-c-using-boost-signals2-and-th

Answer (score 0):

If unde Windows, you can use `CreateProcess` and `WaitForSingleObject` methods. I believe you can pass a timeout to WaitForSingleObject.

If *nix, check out the functionality of `fork()`/`wait()`.